# python: sudo context manager?

Tags: python, sudo, contextmanager

Is there any possible way to implement a `sudo` context manager which runs the enclosing scope as another user, using the sudoers system?

```
system('whoami')  # same result as echo $USER
with sudo():
    system('whoami')  # root
```

I doubt that the `sudo(8)` executable will help me here, but maybe there is some C-level interface that I can bind to?

---

Motivation: I can *almost* port this shell script entirely to python without even any subprocesses, except I currently have to `system('sudo sh -c "echo %i > /dev/thatfile"' % value)`. It would be so elegant if I could `with sudo(), open('/dev/thatfile', 'w') as thatfile: thatfile.write(str(value))`.

Comment: There's `sudo` command in [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/api/core/operations.html?highlight=sudo#fabric.operations.sudo), you might want to review fabric source code to review how it's done there.

Comment: @J0HN: I looked at it briefly. It looks like it just prepends "sudo " to commands later executed by ssh. My goal (if it's even possible) is to do such without a shell.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is not possible in any simple way. Programs that escalate their permissions like `sudo` must have a flag set in their file system permissions (the is the "setuid" bit) in order to tell the operating system to run them as a different user than the one that started them up. Unless you want your whole Python interpreter to be setuid root, there's no direct way to do something equivalent for just some small part of your Python code.

It might conceivably be possible to implement a `sudo` style context manager not by making your regular Python code run privileged, but rather by temporarily replacing the library code that makes various OS calls (such as `open`ing a file) with some kind of proxy that connects it to a setuid helper program. But it would be a lot of work to get something like that to work, and a lot more work to make sure it was secure enough to use anywhere in production.

An idea, if you don't like your current solution of using a shell script from a `system` call: Write the file using regular Python code, with your regular user permissions. Then `chown` it (and move it, if necessary) with a `sudo` call.